# How to have `\n` significant except when it is on a line by itself?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Here is what I have tried:

```
parse : statement (NL statement)* EOF ;

statement : assignment '.' #assignmentStatement
          | empty_line     #emptyLineStatement
          ;

// bunch of stuff omitted for brevity

empty_line : WS* NL+ ;          // want to ignore empty lines
WS : (' '|'\r'|'\t')+ -> skip ; // ignore whitespace
NL : '\n';                      // new line is significant
```

Here is my test input:

```
PI -> 3.14159265359.

sqr(x) x * x.
z -> sqr(x:3).

circumference(r) PI * sqr(x:r).

fib(x) fib(x:x-1) + fib(x:x-2).
fib(x:2) 1.
fib(x:1) 1.
fib(x:0) 0.
```

I get the following error from the parser:

```
line 2:0 no viable alternative at input '\n'
line 5:0 no viable alternative at input '\n'
line 7:0 no viable alternative at input '\n'
```

and the following output from my `Visitor`:

```
PI = 3.14159265359;;
ASSIGN sqr WITH x FROM [] RETURNING x TIMES x;
ASSIGN z AS CALL sqr WITH x = 3;
ASSIGN circumference WITH r FROM [] RETURNING PI TIMES CALL sqr WITH x = r;
ASSIGN fib WITH x FROM [] RETURNING CALL fib WITH x = x MINUS 1 PLUS CALL fib WITH x = x MINUS 2;
IF fib MATCHES x = 2 RETURN 1;
IF fib MATCHES x = 1 RETURN 1;
IF fib MATCHES x = 0 RETURN 0
```

If I remove the empty lines it does not produce the parser error and everything parses as expected:

```
PI -> 3.14159265359.
sqr(x) x * x.
z -> sqr(x:3).
circumference(r) PI * sqr(x:r).
fib(x) fib(x:x-1) + fib(x:x-2).
fib(x:2) 1.
fib(x:1) 1.
fib(x:0) 0.
```

with the expected output of:

```
PI = 3.14159265359;;
ASSIGN sqr WITH x FROM [] RETURNING x TIMES x;
ASSIGN z AS CALL sqr WITH x = 3;
ASSIGN circumference WITH r FROM [] RETURNING PI TIMES CALL sqr WITH x = r;
ASSIGN fib WITH x FROM [] RETURNING CALL fib WITH x = x MINUS 1 PLUS CALL fib WITH x = x MINUS 2;
IF fib MATCHES x = 2 RETURN 1;
IF fib MATCHES x = 1 RETURN 1;
IF fib MATCHES x = 0 RETURN 0
```

I have tried various variations of the `empty_line` rule but it never changes so I am missing something very fundamental.

#### How can I get this to parse an empty line that has only a `\n` or all `whitespace` and a `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

I changed:

```
NL : '\n' ;
```

to:

```
NL : '\n'+ ;
```

and the errors went away!

#### Note:

*This does not address the ability to match an empty line as significant.*